# Paypal IPN keeps failing in Paypal's opinion

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I use the following listener based on the PHP sample provided by Paypal to process their IPN (I'm using Symfony) :

```
public function paypalIPNListenerAction(){

    // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
    // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
    // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
    define("DEBUG", 1);

    // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
    // define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);
    define("LOG_FILE", "ipn.log");

    // Read POST data
    // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2)
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
    // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
    if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    } else {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }
    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    if ($ch == FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    }

    // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
    // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
    // This is mandatory for some environments.
    $cert = __DIR__ . "/../../../../web/cacert.pem";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    } else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
    $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
    $res = trim(end($tokens));
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ')." verified ? : ".strcmp($res, 'VERIFIED')." $res : ".$res. PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

    if(DEBUG == true)
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ')." verified ? : ".strcmp($res, "VERIFIED")." response : ".$res);

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

        $em = $this->getdoctrine();
        $manager = $em->getmanager();

        $id = $myPost['custom'];
        $payment_status = $myPost['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $myPost['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $myPost['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $myPost['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $myPost['receiver_email'];

        $processed = $em->getrepository("ArtforsmileMainBundle:Panier")->getbytxn($txn_id);

        if(!$processed && $payment_status == "completed" && $payment_currency == "eur" && $receiver_email == "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx"){
            /* Interacting with the database */
        }               
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
        // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
    }

    return new Response("ok", Response::HTTP_OK, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
}
```

The IPN are received and answered by the server and the database updated but Paypal keeps thinking they failed. What did I forget ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Need to look at your web server logs to see exactly what HTTP response is getting sent back to PayPal.  May also want to look into these [tips for testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).